# Selenium: How to verify a word in a string inside a variable?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I'd like to know how to verify if there's a word inside a string (using variables).

For example, I have a variable called **options** that has a string "**test,test2,test3**" (without quotes) inside it. I want to verify if this string contains the word **test2**.

I've tried this way:

1. command: **store** // target: **test,test2,test3** // value: **options**
2. command: **storeEval** // target: **javascript{storedVars['options'].contains("test2");}** // value: **result**

I want Selenium to store TRUE or FALSE on that variable result if it finds or not the word test2 on this string, but I'm getting this error:

[error] Unexpected Exception: TypeError: storedVars.options.contains is not a function. fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js, lineNumber -> 2545

Any ideas?

Screenshoot: http://oi40.tinypic.com/2qibcxf.jpg

Comment: Is it ok if you do it in plain javascript?

Comment: how to? I'm really beginner, I just have Selenium IDE installed...do I need to install something else?

Comment: I can't quite remember as its been a while since I used the IDE but I'm fairly sure you'll need to loop over the contents of your `options` array to find your boolean result.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x6cva/

A very simple example

Comment: javascript{storedVars['options'].search("test2");} worked for me, it returned -1 or 0, it's all that I want, thanks for the support!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**javascript{storedVars['options'].search("test2");}** worked.

Comment: If you've found the solution yourself, then you should accept the answer; that takes your question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the IDE, you can simply use the command below:

```
verifyTextPresent | storedVars['options'] | test2
```

This line will pass (turn green) if the text is found, and will fail (red) if it isn't.

Klendathu

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, actually I used storeEval / '${variable}'.search("term") / variable_name, because I wanted it to find and store true or false if it finds or not, the verifyTextPresent command only shows green/red lines without storing a boolean value :)